# Scale the X and Y axis of a scatterplot to fill the whole axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I asked this question before in a previous post. I understood that some things were not as clearly mentioned as I thought. Therefore I have created an 100% functional reproductional code which should show why the data within `Function{}` cannot be changed (as suggested in prevrious post).

Reproductional code (just copy, paste and execute and you'll get three graphs):

```
df <- data.frame(
                            ID = c(1L,1L,
                                   1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                                   1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L,3L,3L,3L,
                                   3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L),
                             x = as.integer(c(14400L,
                                   13400L,12600L,11600L,10500L,9520L,8540L,
                                   7710L,6580L,4540L,3710L,2880L,1440L,
                                   0L,-10000L,-20900L,-31800L,-42700L,
                                   -53600L,-64500L,-75400L,165000L,74300L,62800L,52600L,35000L,
                                   22200L,6090L,0L,-10000L,-16500L,-23000L,-29500L,-36000L,
                                   -42500L,-49000L,97900L,
                                   51100L,22900L,4410L,0L,-5000L,
                                   -7280L,-9560L,-11840L,
                                   -14120L)),
                          U.x. = c(1,
                                   0.923076923,0.846153846,0.769230769,
                                   0.692307692,0.615,0.538,0.462,0.385,0.308,0.231,
                                   0.154,0.077,0,-2.723,-3.134,-9.393,
                                   -34.664,-58.576,-188.332,-307.888,1,0.857,0.714,0.571,0.429,0.286,0.143,
                                   0,-0.091,-0.238,-0.265,-0.447,-0.472,-0.507,-0.574,1,0.75,
                                   0.5,0.25,0,-0.142,-0.193,
                                   -0.322,-0.56,-0.755))

ID = c(0) #Needs to be set before starting the function, otherwise the first plot wont be generated

plot_utility <- function(ID) {
  x = df$x[df$ID==ID]
  y = df$U.x.[df$ID==ID]
  z = df$ID[df$ID==ID]
  df1 = data.frame(df$ID[df$ID==ID], df$U.x.[df$ID==ID],
                   df$x[df$ID==ID])
  # Set boundaries and stepsize for x-axis
  lowboundx <- df[df$ID==ID,][nrow(df[df$ID==ID,]), 2]
  upboundx <- df[df$ID==ID,][1, 2]
  
  # Determine sequence for x-axis with respectively lower bound (seq1) and upper bound (seq2) 
  seq1x <- floor(lowboundx / 5000) * 5000
  seq2x <- ceiling(upboundx / 5000) * 5000
  
  # Set boundaries and stepsize for y-axis
  lowboundy <- df[df$ID==ID,][nrow(df[df$ID==ID,]), 3]
  upboundy <- df[df$ID==ID,][1, 3]
  
  # Determine sequence for x-axis with respectively lower bound (seq1) and upper bound (seq2) 
  if(lowboundy <= -55) {
    seq1y <- floor(lowboundy / 50) * 50
    seq2y <- upboundy # This is always 1
  } else {
    seq1y <- round(lowboundy, digits = 3)#ceiling(lowboundy / 50) * 50
    seq2y <- upboundy # This is always 1
  }
  
ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(shape=15) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Euro", limits = c(seq1x, seq2x), labels = comma) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="U(x)", limits = c(seq1y, seq2y)) +
  labs(title = paste("Subject", ID))
  
}

repeat {
  ID = ID + 1
  print(plot_utility(ID))
  print(ID)
  if (ID == 3){
    break
  }
}
```

What is my issue:

As shown in Subject 1:

On the right hand side of the graph the x axis ends with 0, but there are still dots after this 0. The x axis needs to be extended to 20,000

As shown in Subject 2

This is a more difficult example as the others but the principle is the same. There is a dot outside of an label on the x axis. There needs to be an extra label which says 200,000. This sounds a bit extreme but I prefer that over the current graph

As shown in Subject 3

In the left down corner (where y and x axis come together), there are dots outside of the labels on the axis (-0.5 and 0) I need this to get resolved into something like extra labels (-1.0 and -25,000) These would be an additional break point (i guess thats what it is called)
The y axis should look something like this (from below to up):
-1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0
The x axis should look like (from left to right):
-25,000 | 0 | 25,000 | 50,000 | 75,000 | 100,000

As noticable, it is not possible to change this through `limits =` at `scale_x_continuous` as this would mutate all of the other graphs as well which is not realy desired.

Any solution to my problem would be appreciated a lot! :)
(Please note: the data.frame was reverse engineerd in order to create this example, please don't pay attention to the unnecessary naming of values further up in the code :))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a case for faceting using `facet_grid()`. If you need individual plots, then this is not the solution for you. When you facet a plot, you can set `scales = "free"` to accomplish your desired end. Note also that this approach does not need such complex code.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = U.x.)) +
  geom_point(shape=15) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Euro") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="U(x)") +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(ID), scales = "free", labeller = label_both)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need those graphs to be seperated from each other. I understand that it wouldn't need to be so complex but I am not aware of creating something easier than this when it comes to create 28 different graphs. Besides that, there are some graphs with x values(or labels) over 7million. This would realy mess with the other graphs as it is getting scaled over fixed values, right?